# Vite Webpage showing blank after deploying to netlify

Tags: github, vite, netlify, mime

My code works fine and I pushed it to github. But wheni deployed it to netlify, the webpage was showing black and i get Error:
`/src/main.jsx:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/octet-stream". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`
I have tried to change the run command on netlify but no chnage.